# Rails 5 API - how to include multiple models in JSON response

Tags: rails-api

In a Rails 5 API app with active_model_serializers, I can send a response that contains `include` option for one model only and it works:

```
UsersController

json: @current_user, status: :ok, include: 'shop'
```

a **User** `belongs_to` a **Shop**, and a **Shop** `has_one` **Address**.

How is it possible to include a Address associated to the Shop to the response ?
Thank you.

Comment: you added the UserSerializer inside serializer folder ? Also need to add a Shopserializer with has_one address

Comment: @praga2050, yes, I have `UserSerializer`, `AddresSerializer` and `ShopSerializer as well. If I add `has_one :address` it will include Address for every of ~2000 shops. I think I'll have to redesign all this. Thank you.

Comment: I believed that it was possible to include multiple associations into the response like with AR models: `Article.includes(:category, :comments)`.

Comment: good to know. Let me know if u need further help